# The Unit Test does not see my methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I created a unit Test project for my CalculatorApp and added the app as a reference for my UniTest Project

My code looks like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using CalculatorApp;


    namespace CalculatorUnitTests
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class UnitTest1
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public void TestAddMethod()
            {
                decimal firstTestNumber = 7;
                decimal secondTestNumber = 3;
                decimal resultTest = 10;


                Assert.AreEqual(resultTest, AddMethod(firstTestNumber, secondTestNumber));

            }
    }
```

But it says that AddMethod does not exist in the current context.

What am I missing? (i don't have much experience with unitTests)
I am using Visual Studio Community 2015.

Comment: Same reason you can't just call `AddMethod` from any random place: you need a reference to the surrounding object and call it like a proper method invocation.

Comment: You never created a `CalculatorApp` instance. I'm not sure why you expected `AddMethod(firstTestNumber, secondTestNumber)` to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jeroen already mentioned, you need an instance of the calculator class you want to test. Try editing your test in a way like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestAddMethod()
{
    decimal firstTestNumber = 7;
    decimal secondTestNumber = 3;
    decimal expected = 10;

    // create an instance of your system under test (sut)
    var sut = new CalculatorApp.Calculator();

    // invoke the method, you want to test and keep the actual result
    var actual = sut.AddMethod(firstTestNumber, secondTestNumber)

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```